# What happens when dependency uses different logging?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

Suppose I have a web project (war) which is using logback logging but this project has a dependency of a jar which internally uses log4j logging. What will happen in this case? Will dependency logs appear in my logback log file or they just disappear (means I wont be able to see them anywhere) or some exception?

Answer (score 1):

The logs coming from your dependency won't appear in your log file unless you use a bridge to redirect calls made to log4j by calls made to your logger.

If you use logback with slf4j, you can refer to this link to have more explanation on how to do that : http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html